# Spray.io Path Directives serve index.html

Tags: scala, spray

I want to set up a Spray route to serve web content out of a directory.

For example, the below URLs should resolve to the same file.

http://mywebsite.com/path/to/thing

http://mywebsite.com/path/to/thing/

http://mywebsite.com/path/to/thing/index.html

Should serve the index.html file from the filesystem at ./web/path/to/thing/index.html

The following route works if "index.html" is explicitly specified but not otherwise.

```
pathPrefix("") {
  getFromDirectory("./web/")
}
```

How do i represent this in Spray routing?

Comment: Did that work for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have already matched up to "thing" with `pathPrefix`, I think you want `pathEndOrSingleSlash`, described [here](http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.3/spray-routing/path-directives/pathEndOrSingleSlash/).  I didn't think that Spray-routing would match an implicit "index.html", but in any case you can compose directives easily if you need to:

```
(pathEndOrSingleSlash | path("index.html")) { ... }
```

UPDATE:

OK, from your comment I am thinking that you just want to take whatever path was specified and serve up the file from that directory. Something like this (untested)?

```
path(Segment) { rawPath =>
  getFromFile("web/" + if (rawPath endsWith "/") rawPath + "index.html" else rawPath)
}
```

Comment: Here's where my problem lies, I don't explicitly match up to thing. My routes are not hard-coded in this way. I need all directories in the folder to behave the same way. if you specify a path to a folder (not a file), it should look for a index.html there.

Comment: @Upio - I *think* I understand what you are after, and updated the answer.  Please let me know whether that was what you wanted.